# Как поменять папку сессий для garbage collector?

Tags: php, сборщик-мусора

С помощью `ini_set('session.save_path', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/log/session');` была изменена папка сохранения сессий, от чего(могу ошибаться) **garbage collector** не очищает папку с сессиями(так как не указана новая папка).
Вопрос: как указать для него эту папку с сессиями? Есть ли возможность сделать это не задействуя **php.ini**?

Answer (score 0):

Папку вы уже указали. Есть еще другие переменные. Возможно, чтобы была очистка надо их выставить. Также через php_ini

> **session.gc_probability int**
> session.gc_probability в сочетании с session.gc_divisor определяет вероятность запуска функции сборщика мусора (gc, garbage collection).
> По умолчанию равен 1. Смотрите подробнее в session.gc_divisor.
> session.gc_divisor int
> **session.gc_divisor** в сочетании с session.gc_probability определяет вероятность запуска функции сборщика мусора (gc, garbage collection)
> при каждой инициализации сессии. Вероятность рассчитывается как
> gc_probability/gc_divisor, то есть 1/100 означает, что функция gc
> запускается в одном случае из ста, или 1% при каждом запросе.
> session.gc_divisor по умолчанию имеет значение 100.
> session.gc_maxlifetime int
> **session.gc_maxlifetime** задаёт отсрочку времени в секундах, после которой данные будут рассматриваться как "мусор" и потенциально будут
> удалены. Сбор мусора может произойти в течение старта сессии (в
> зависимости от значений session.gc_probability и session.gc_divisor).

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php

Можете сами простенький скрипт удаления файлов написать.

Comment: А если я поставил эти значения 
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 100);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 4);
перед session_start(), но сессия с вероятностью в 100% и временем жизни 4 сек не удаляется. Где я мог совершить ошибку?

Comment: Не могу ответить.  Надо более детально разбираться как gc работает, и какие причины могут быть.  Если бы меня на практике волновал этот вопрос и не было времени в теории ковырятся, я бы в цикле unlink сделал - удалил бы все файлы старше 4 сек.